# Adding portlets to page dynamically in liferay

Tags: java, layout, liferay, portlet

I have a liferay page where it should have a freeform layout, but the number of portlets is not know before run time. How can i add protlets dynamically and sepcify their location in the page?

Thank you.

Comment: see this link https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/3575947

Comment: also this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395944/how-to-add-nested-portletsliferay-through-code

Comment: but i don't want to add a portlet from another portlet, i want to add all portlets to a page at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add portlets to a page dynamically.

In liferay page is known as `Layout` and you add portlets to a `Layout`.

The code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8448309/468763) (refer the `addPortlet` method) will help you add a portlet to a page when you know the layout i.e. you know the page to which the portlets need to be added.

Also you need to specify the `column` to which the portlet would be added on the page.

You mentioned:

> but i don't want to add a portlet from another portlet, i want to add all portlets to a page at run time.

The piece of code would remain the same irrespective of the fact that you want to add portlets through a portlet or through a action class like when the User logins you call the code to add portlets inside of the `LoginPostAction` or through when some other action is performed.