# Liferay Custom Welcome Page

Tags: liferay, liferay-velocity

I have requirement such that, to configure the welcome page of User’s Private Page with my custom portlets dynamically. On successful login  User lands to his private page. Based on his roles he should see the portlets on the auto created welcome page. User1 has to see portlet A and User2 has to see portlet B.

Comment: can you elaborate more on your requirement?

Comment: i have updated the question. is this ok?

Comment: Not Exactly. Do you want that user should see portlets based on his role then you can give VIEW permission for portlet based on role. Also if you want it like user can put portlet he wants on his private page then you should give UPDATE permission in pages to USER role.

Comment: The thing is user do have update permission. On the users first login his layout has to be created dynamically. Leave the roles part.

Comment: check if this helps you in any way https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/17676547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify and add portlets to page (Layout) problematically by the Action that fired by first user login. See this answer [How to add nested portlets(liferay) through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395944/how-to-add-nested-portletsliferay-through-code/8448309#8448309) .